# Trouble adding 2 shapes to a JFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm planning on making a very simple game where a square moves along a 2 dimensional floor. To do this I need to add 2 shapes but for some reason they won't appear on the screen. I think there's something wrong with the code for drawing the actual shape since when I omit the part where I add a second shape it still doesn't work. If anyone could point out errors in my code so that I can fix them (I'm not concerned with the keylistener code at the minute) then that would be really helpful.

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class mainClass3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setSize(600,400);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    window.setLayout(null);
    Graphics3 DC = new Graphics3();
    window.addKeyListener(DC);
    window.add(DC);
    Floor2 floor = new Floor2();
    window.add(floor);

        }

    }
```

Graphics Class (for the square) :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Graphics3 extends JComponent implements KeyListener{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 200;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,100,100);
        Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;
        rect.setLocation(x,y);
        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.fill(rect);      
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x-=1;
    }


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

 }
```

Other Graphics class (for the floor):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Floor2 extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent2(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Rectangle floor1 = new Rectangle (0,300,600,100);
        floor1.setLocation(permanentx,permanenty);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fill(floor1);        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.setLayout(null);` is one of your issues.  The layout management API does some very important jobs, positioning and sizing components automatically based on the layout implementation, which you've just gone and thrown away.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

The other is attempting to use components in this way.

I would recommend changing tack slightly.  Instead of using two different components, create a single component which acts as the "game surface".  This is where ALL the relative painting is done, floor AND rectangle.  This provides a better self contained environment which is easier to control and maintain.

Before you post your next question on *"why my `KeyListener` doesn't work"* - Take a look at [How to use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will fix the focus issues related with `KeyListener`

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code here and there, but it finally works. I decided to use a `null` layout, because it was appropriate in this situation. Anyway, here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class mainClass3 {

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        // Never forget to manipulate swing objects under the event dispatch queue.
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            // I'll use the null layout. Don't blame me.
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            // Specifies the position, as well as the width and height of the square.
            final Rectangle rectangle01 = new Rectangle(5, 200, 100, 100);
            // Determines the position and size of the floor.
            final Rectangle rectangle02 = new Rectangle(0, 300, 600, 100);
            // Now, here is the first big difference between your and my code: composition over inheritance.
            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            final JPanel square = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
                    super.paintComponent(graphics);
                    graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, rectangle01.width, rectangle01.height);
                    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectangle01.width, rectangle01.height);
                }
            };
            // Let's also add a working key listener, shall we?
            frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent event) {
                    super.keyPressed(event);
                    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                        square.setLocation(square.getX() + 6, square.getY());
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                        square.setLocation(square.getX() - 6, square.getY());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
            // Don't forget to set the bounds of a component when working with a null layout!
            square.setBounds(rectangle01);
            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            final JPanel floor = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {
                    super.paintComponent(graphics);
                    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, rectangle02.width, rectangle02.height);
                    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, rectangle02.width, rectangle02.height);
                }
            };
            // And don't forget to set the bounds here too.
            floor.setBounds(rectangle02);
            // Now, just add all components to the frame. Voilà!
            frame.add(square);
            frame.add(floor);
        });
    }    
}
```

Just wanted to thank you for answering one of my questions by the way.